# apex_web_service.parse_xml with namespace issue

Tags: plsql, apex

```
I am getting below XML and wanted to get value of (<ns3:AdjustmentId>300012939858528</ns3:AdjustmentId>) AdjustmentId. I am using apex_web_service.parse_xml function but getting error as below. Can someone help me how to handle namespace here.
```

--------- Code
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
env:Header
wsa:Actionhttp://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/</wsa:Action>
wsa:MessageIDurn:uuid:b2d84629-e765-4a9f-aa3c-6e1a74200c31</wsa:MessageID>
</env:Header>
env:Body
<ns0:findAdjustmentResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/receivables/transactions/adjustments/adjustmentService/types/">
<ns4:result xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/receivables/transactions/adjustments/model/flex/AdjustmentsDff/" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/flex/financials/receivables/transactions/adjustments/AdjustmentGdf/" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/receivables/transactions/adjustments/adjustmentService/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/receivables/transactions/adjustments/adjustmentService/types/" xsi:type=`enter code here`"ns3:Adjustment">
<ns3:AcctdAmount currencyCode="USD">10</ns3:AcctdAmount>
ns3:AdjustmentId300012939858528</ns3:AdjustmentId>
ns3:AdjustmentNumber3221276</ns3:AdjustmentNumber>

```
Thanks,
Prakash
```